# Solidity Log Event Meta Data

Tags: solidity, remix, events

The log file created using event is shown below.  Is it possible to show the variable names of the fields that the values are being displayed.

[image: Log File]

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want the hex values in string?  Or do you want the variable names printed out with it?

Comment: Hi @thefett, thanks for your reply.   I wanted to see the variable names printed out with it.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the event to place the name first:

```
contract Test {

    uint public number;

    event Print(string _name, uint _value);

    function setnum(uint _num) public{
      number = _num;
      Print("number",number);
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi @thefett.   This works for now but in a round about way.  The variable name and the value falls in two separate lines and it requires the variable name to be hardcoded again in the event execution.   I was trying to get the same format as the "decoded input" in the Log file, which has the variable name along with the value.  I am not sure if that is possible for now.

Comment: Ah I see, I don't think it is possible without hardcoding it.  The 'logs' portion is just the decoded logsBloom which you can see here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/how-does-ethereum-make-use-of-bloom-filters is just stored data, so if you don't specify what you're storing, then it can't figure it out from just the logs data