# What is bloombits?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, fast-sync, geth-debugging

I'm syncing my node with geth and I used the light mode.

**>start geth --syncmode "light"**

Then a parameter type="bloombits" appeared. What is bloombits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At its simplest, from [`doc.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/c4d21bc8e548d909d5b2940cb00d3d068f5697ec/core/bloombits/doc.go#L18):

```
// Package bloombits implements bloom filtering on batches of data.
package bloombits
```

Of interest: [How does Ethereum make use of bloom filters?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/how-does-ethereum-make-use-of-bloom-filters) (In short, to allow efficient searching over event logs.)

One step further back: [Bloom Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) (Wikipedia)

Comment: Great I get it, so it's only used when light mode? That would be logic since it needs less memory?

Comment: It's not just specific to light mode, no :-)